# Set foreign key to string when storing in database in Laravel 5.7

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have `users` table and `activity_log` table. In `users` table, `id` value is stored in the form of an unique string. While storing any value in the `activity_log` table, `causer_id` which is the foreign key to `users.id` field stored 0 value.

I tried to change the keytype of `causer_id` in modal.

```
protected $keyType = 'string';
public $incrementing = false;
```

But I think this is for the primary key not for the foreign key. I also change type of `causer_id` in `activity_log` table to varchar but it will get stored 0 value.

For storing data inside `activity_log` table, I used [laravel-activitylog](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-activitylog) package

```
$activity = activity()
            ->causedBy(\Auth::user())
            ->performedOn($user)
            ->withProperties($properties)
            ->log($changes);
```

Comment: I believe the foreign key must be the same type as the primary key it is related to.

Comment: Yes. It is the same as the primary key.